# Best way to execute a SQL Server script using ASP.NET and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I've been trying to find the best way to execute a SQL server script using ASP.NET and Jquery for an internal automation test editor. I currently have a JQuery function to call for my ASP WebMethod to perform the SQL connection and execute the query, but I'm currently sending the query as a parameter to this ASP function and I know this is not a safe way to do it and I also run into problems when I have large scripts due to the special characters (I tried using escape and other similar functions but I could not decode it correctly from ASP side).

So my question is if anyone knows what would be the best way to handle the scripts to be executed? A control table on SQL Server or a session variable maybe?

Here is the current code I have.

**JQuery**

```
        function ExecuteScript() {
            var script = document.getElementById('MainContent_textEditor').innerHTML;
            $('#MainContent_textEditorResponse').html(encodeURIComponent(script));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/ExecuteScript",
                data: "{'sqlQuery':'"+script+"'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: ExecuteScript_Success,
                error: ExecuteScript_Error
            });
             return false;
        }
        function ExecuteScript_Success(mydata) {
            $('#MainContent_textEditorResponse').html(mydata.d);
        }
        function ExecuteScript_Error(mydata) {
        }
```

**ASP.NET**

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string ExecuteScript(string sqlQuery)
        {
            string connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DQSQLAutomationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string queryResult = "";

            using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connectionString))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("TestCases");
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    queryResult = queryResult + dt.Rows[i][0];
                }
                return queryResult;
            }
        }
```

I also tried to access the textarea control from ASP.NET to get the script but I can't access a non static element from a static function.

Comment: Why does this have to flow through an AJAX call instead of a normal page postback?

Comment: The best way is to use parameterized SQL queries and precompiled execution plans. If you are using MS SQL-Server, you should consider stored procedures. Never build a query from user provided data, whether it comes from AJAX or HTTP parameters. Users should only control parameters for queries, not the queries themselves, and the parameters should be validated before any query is executed.

Comment: thank you @Graham, yeah I was doing all the other functionality using Ajax but I guess I will try using a regular postback for this.